# Fazer a injeção de múltiplos IDbConnection no Asp.Net core

Tags: asp.net-core, interface, injeção-de-dependência

Bom dia pessoal, 
tudo bem?

Preciso fazer a injeção de 2 DBContext no asp.net core e estou tendo problemas com isso.
Segue o exemplo de código.

```
    string defaultConnectionA = _configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnectionA");
    services.AddTransient<IDbConnection>(x => new SqlConnection(defaultConnectionA));

    string defaultConnectionB = _configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnectionB");
    services.AddTransient<IDbConnection>(x => new SqlConnection(defaultConnectionB));
```

Fazendo dessa forma, ele deixa apenas o ultimo como ativo.

Tentei criar uma interface nova e herdei da "IDbConnection", porém, não deu certo.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

obrigado
abs

Answer (score 0):

tudo bem?

Você pode usar uma extensão do EF Core, nesse caso você precisa definir seus contextos herdando do DBContext:

Uso assim:

```
   services.AddDbContext<DbContext1>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString1"],
                                 sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                                 {
                                     sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name);
                                     //Configuring Connection Resiliency: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency 
                                     sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 10, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                                 });
        });

  services.AddDbContext<DbContext2>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString2"],
                                     sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                                     {
                                         sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name);
                                         //Configuring Connection Resiliency: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency 
                                         sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 10, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                                     });
            });
```

As configurações do sqlServerOptionsActions podem ser removidas, mas no caso do exemplo, a primeira trata a definição de onde o Migrations será gerenciado (No caso no meu projeto uso sempre a camada "Application" e a segunda é um tratamento de politica de retry, no caso utilizo a nuvem então é necessário por causa da latência.